# Is there a Python equivalent to Stream.findAny()?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, iterator, java-stream

I want to find the message for a given hash value. To do this, I want to iterate over the set of all possible n-length permutations of ascii lowercase and numbers and check if the hash of the permutation equals a given hash value.

**Problem**: Precalculating the set is not feasible since the space complexity is O(36^n).

**Idea**: In Java, I would create a Stream producing these permutations and use findAny() after applying a filter. Due to lazy evaluation, there is no need to compute all possible permutations in advance.

**Question**: Is there some equivalent in Python which mimics this behaviour? I guess itertools could be tweaked to work like this but I'm not sure.

Appreciate any kind of feedback!

Comment: Yes, you could do this with itertools, which has a permutations generator

Comment: Doesn't permutations() generate a full size array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generators is what you are looking for:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

```
def foo(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num
        num += 1

f = foo(5)
print f.next() // 0
print f.next() // 1
print f.next() // 2
```

In this example, each call to f.next() calculates and returns next value.

You can think about it like yield returns a value and wait for another `next` call.

Comment: I'm just not sure how a next() function would work on strings. I thought Generators are more for integers?

Comment: No, you can return anything you want. Even objects with different types each time.